# Populating missing rows in postgresql

Tags: perl, postgresql, hash

I have written a `CGI script in perl`. I am receiving `POST request` to that script from two different locations simultaneously. 
From POST request i am populating five different tables. I get 500 rows in each POST request and then i populate each table with 100 rows.

My issue is that after some time one or two of the table start showing less number of rows. Both of these tables store ip in one of their column. Every time only these two tables are the one which is missing data which is weird for me. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Although i receive something in postgresql logs and number of such logs are same as the number of rows missing from table.

```
UTC STATEMENT:  insert into post (ip, count, location, source_server) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
UTC STATEMENT:  insert into post (ip, count, location, source_server) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
UTC STATEMENT:  insert into post (ip, count, location, source_server) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

This is my CGI code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use DBI;
use JSON;


#Taking parameters passed as post request
my $conn = CGI->new;
my $data = $conn->param('POSTDATA');

#Details regarding database
my $host     = 'host';
my $user     = 'user';
my $password = 'password';
my $database = 'db';

my ( $location, $table, $entry );

#Creating connection to DB
my $dsn = "dbi:Pg:dbname=$database;host=$host";
my $dbh
    = DBI->connect( $dsn, $user, $password,
    { RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0 } )
    or die("Connection to DB failed $!\n");

#Decoding json received in post request to perl hash
$data = decode_json $data;

my ($source_server) = keys %$data;

my $location = 'XX';

my $main_data = $$data{$source_server};

my @db      = qw /a b c d e/;
my %mapping = (
    'a'   => 'A',
    'b'     => 'B',
    'c' => 'C',
    'd' => 'D',
    'e'   => 'E'
);


foreach (@$main_data) {

    my $hash = $_;

    #Deciding which table data will be pushed into
    $table = shift @db;
    $entry = $mapping{$table};

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        "insert into $table ($entry, count, location, source_server) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    while ( ( my $key, my $value ) = each %$hash ) {
        $sth->execute( $key, $value, $location, $source_server );

    }
    $sth->finish;

}

#Sending 200 status code back to client
print "Status: 200\n\n";
```

Data is passed to my CGI script in JSON as `{KEY : [{HASH},{HASH},{HASH},{HASH},{HASH}]}`. Second and fifth hash contains data for tables which are missing it after some time.

Every hash will have 100 key:value pairs thus making total 500 entries.

Comment: How do you know the order of the data? The `keys %$data` and the `shift @db` sound like stuff is going wrong. Probalby that's just for the example though.

Comment: Have you added a log or examined the web server log? Also add `or die $dbh->errstr` to your prepare and execute or turn on `PrintError` and `RaiseError`. Maybe the source data is wrong. You could also add a transaction around the `while`, or even the `foreach`.

Comment: @simbabque Since there is only one key in JSON so i can take that key using `keys %$data`. Also i am getting array of hashes and order in which arrays are placed is fixed and that i know for sure. Since i have to enter in 5 tables which are varying by only one column so to get table and one varying column i created @db and %mapping.

Comment: @simbabque Yes i examined web server logs and they are have entry in only access logs and nothing in error logs. But i will try other things.

Comment: @simbabque Turning on `PrintError` and `RaiseError` helped me to identify the problem and solve. Since i was getting data from more than one places it was messing with my primary key constraint thus causing the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I was helpful. Leave your own answer with at least an abstract of what you did, so others can understand, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Well after simbabque comment above i enabled `RaiseError` and `PrintError`. After this i am able to get error in server error logs. Error logs indicate that because of simultaneous insertion of rows coming from multiple places i am getting primary key violation which was causing this strange behaviour.

I tweaked my primary key and all is well :)